How to get the terraform state file of already created virtual machines in openstack
I would like to know if it is possible to use terraform or some other tool to obtain state files of already created virtual machines in openstack?
I need this because I have a lot of virtual machines and they cannot be recreated because services run on them, but I would like to have descriptions of these machines in terrafrom.
I tried to find some solution, but didn't find anything suitable

you can use terraformer to import all resources at once.
Example:
terraformer import openstack --resources=compute,networking --regions=RegionOne

List of supported OpenStack services:
blockstorage:

openstack_blockstorage_volume_v1
openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2
openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3

compute:

openstack_compute_instance_v2

networking:

openstack_networking_secgroup_v2
openstack_networking_secgroup_rule_v2

